# YouTube Feeds V3

Tags: youtube

YouTube deprecated V2 so now I cannot fetch movie trailers, I was using the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q={$mov.title|replace:" ":'+'}+Trailer&alt=json-in-script&callback=ShowMovies&max-results=1">
```

I was hoping someone could help me make this code work with the V3 API so that it will fetch the movie trailers again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an API key now, and there is a quota for requests.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/